# CodeIgniter Getting Not Found Image Path In Session

Tags: codeigniter, session, redirect

I'm implementing redirect to previous page after `login` and `logout`.

So in each methods of controller I've saved session like as follow.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('previous_page', current_url());
```

And after successful `login` and `logout`, I'm calling a library method as follows.

```
function redirect_to_previous_url() {

    $url = base_url();

    if($this->_CI->session->userdata('previous_page')) {

        // Get previous_url
        $url = $this->_CI->session->userdata('previous_page');

        $this->_CI->session->unset_userdata('previous_page');
    }

    return $url;
}
```

But Its redirecting to `base_url` of the site. After checking the session value Its showing not found image path but not what I've saved it before.

I'm not able to find out what is the problem behind this.
Please help me to rectify and the work would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
function redirect_to_previous_url() {

$url = base_url();

if($this->_CI->session->userdata('previous_page')) {

    // Get previous_url
    $url = $this->_CI->session->userdata('previous_page');

    $this->_CI->session->unset_userdata('previous_page');

    return $url;
}

return $url;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure the session was set. Like this;

```
if($this->_CI->session->userdata('previous_page')) {
    show_error('The session is set');
}
```

If you don't see the error, the session isn't set. Then you know this isn't where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

No need to store Previous URL in session.

In core php you can get previously visited URL in following server variable

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Same can be achieved in CodeIgniter as

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
echo $this->agent->referrer();
```